# Do I have enable compression on nginx?

Tags: nginx, iis-6

I enabled compression on IIS6 and it works. But if I make request through a nginx server (on other server) to my IIS6 server, there is no compression at all.
Do I have to enable compression on nginx? If I have to then there is no need to enable compression on IIS6?

Answer (score 0):

There are headers you need to send to indicate the client supports compression.

You may need to add smth like:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

to your client request. Be careful - you'll need to decompress the result!

**Update:**

In case your server is nginx (and not IIS6) - here is the section explaining how to **[enable compression in nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule)**.

Comment: I open web page using chrome, I am sure there is **Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch**. I am testing request in the both way :(

Comment: I am nginx as a reverse proxy only.